# Problems with Rufus 3.0

Tags: system-installation, usb, rufus

I am currently on a Windows XP laptop and am trying to upgrade to Ubuntu. I even went and got a flash drive for the USB installation of Ubuntu, however when going through the step by step process, I noticed that Rufus (which  is the software used to install the USB) no longer supports Windows XP. I need some assistance as to how I can get maybe an older, more XP friendly version of Rufus because all I really want is an Ubuntu computer.

Comment: This seems like a Windows XP support question.

Comment: You don't need Rufus to create a bootable Ubuntu flash drive. How old is the laptop? And what version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Comment: https://rufus.ie/downloads has ALL the versions of Rufus that were ever released, including the ones that support Windows XP.

Answer (score 2):

### Win32 Disk Imager

Try the cloning tool Win32 Disk Imager. An old version, 0.9, works in Windows XP. See this links,

[Win32 Disk Imager tutorial for cloning iso files](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb)

[sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/)

> For Windows XP/Vista, please use v0.9 (in the files archive).

### Rufus 2.18

Try an older version of Rufus. According to

[github.com/pbatard/rufus/blob/master/ChangeLog.txt](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/blob/master/ChangeLog.txt)

[**Rufus version 2.18**](https://rufus.akeo.ie/downloads/rufus-2.18.exe) works in Windows XP.

> Version 2.18 (2017.11.07)
>       Ensure that the same drive is reselected on device refresh
>       Add a cheat mode to cycle the USB port of currently selected device
>       Make lookup for updatable .cfg file more generic (e.g. ESET SysRescue)
>       Fix handling of multiextent ISOs (e.g. BlackArch Linux)
>       Fix propagation of image decompression errors
>       Update grub4dos to latest
>
> ```
> IMPORTANT: THIS IS THE LAST RELEASE TO SUPPORT WINDOWS XP AND WINDOWS VISTA
> SUBSEQUENT RUFUS RELEASES ARE *NO LONGER* COMPATIBLE WITH THESE PLATFORMS
> ```

Comment: Rufus developer here just to point out that, yes, it's not because we stopped supporting Windows XP with Rufus 3.0 that Rufus 2.18, the last Windows XP compatible version, will cease to work. If you still want to use Rufus on Windows XP, just use 2.18. After all, since you're using XP, you should already be familiar with using __old__ software :) You can find the download at https://rufus.ie/downloads

Answer (score 0):

You could try similar software such as [LinuxLive USB Creator](https://www.linuxliveusb.com) (LiLi).

Failing that, use a computer with a supported OS like Windows 7/8/10 to create the USB installer.

For any further questions about Windows software, please ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Etcher, it is multiplatform, it has never given me problems with the creation of ISO of any Operating System.

You can download it from your Repository on Github: https://github.com/resin-io/etcher